# Is there a connection between contravariant functors and the axiom of choice?

Tags: category-theory, axiom-of-choice

Given that both can be seen as talking about reversing arrows between two objects: Is there a connection between contravariant functors and the axiom of choice? I'm initially motivated geometrical pictures of bundles, where postulating the axiom guarantees the existence of sections.

Comment: The question is very vague.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I agree and it's mostly because I don't want to use names for things I don't properly understand. My idea is that if I postulate that the axiom of choice is true, this implies the existence of kind of an endofunctor which turns arrows between objects $A,B$ in a category $\mathcal C$ in the reversed direction $\mathcal C(A,B)\to\mathcal C(B,A)$.

Comment: This is not even close to the axiom of choice. Sections are not unique or canonical, but functors are canonical.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: It's not even close in the sense that it doesn't provide specific functions?

Comment: Well if $f : A \to B$ is a surjective function, then the axiom of choice tells us that there is an injective function $g:=g(f) : B \to A$ with $fg=1_B$. But this $g$ is not uniquely determined, and I don't think that it can be chosen functorial in the sense that $g(f \circ f') = g(f') \circ g(f)$.